# Getting error while compiling Grails Project in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, codec

While compiling the project, I am getting below mentioned error.

```
:: problems summary ::
 WARNINGS

 UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES     


:: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: configuration not found in commons-   codec#commons-codec;1.6: 'master'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 compile

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Please let me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

grails clean

grails refresh-dependencies

The above two commands helped me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1**

set log level to verbose in `BuilConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

  inherits("global") {
  }

    log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    ...
}
```

You will find commons codec in `~/.grails/ivy-cache`,

```
$ ll ~/.grails/ivy-cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/
total 40
drwx------ 3 prayagupd prayagupd 4096 Feb 25  2014 ./
drwx------ 3 prayagupd prayagupd 4096 Dec 27  2013 ../
-rwx------ 1 prayagupd prayagupd 6289 Dec 27  2013 ivy-1.5.xml*
-rwx------ 1 prayagupd prayagupd 6299 Dec 27  2013 ivy-1.5.xml.original*
-rwx------ 1 prayagupd prayagupd  415 Feb 25  2014 ivy-1.6.xml*
-rwx------ 1 prayagupd prayagupd  660 Nov  4 11:57 ivydata-1.5.properties*
-rwx------ 1 prayagupd prayagupd  383 Nov  4 11:57 ivydata-1.6.properties*
drwx------ 2 prayagupd prayagupd 4096 Feb 25  2014 jars/
```

**STEP 2**

Actually in `verbose` mode, it probably tells you to remove `~/.grails/ivy-cache`,

```
rm -r ~/.grails/ivy-cache
```

**STEP 3**

Fire whatever commands you love,

`grails clean && grails refresh-dependencies && grails compile`

**STEP 4**

After things look good, you can set log level back to `warn` in `BuildConfig.groovy`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some dependencies. Go to you project root folder using a command prompt and run the following Grails command (assuming you have added Grails to your PATH):

```
{project_root_path}/ grails refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: it is "refresh-dependencies ".